# What is the rule to assign memory quota in Couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I have 4 buckets with 11MB, 111MB, 1.1GB and 2.2GB sizes and each of these bucket contains many `views` in different `document design` in standalone mode. How much memory should I assign in these buckets? is there any rule? Any theory behind it?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, for maximum Key-Value performance you want your working set to be 100% resident in RAM. Documents which are not resident in RAM will need to be fetched from disk (typically a number of orders magnitude than reading from RAM).

Take a look at the [Sizing Guidelines](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Concepts/bp-sizingGuidelines.html) section in the Couchbase Admin guide for more details.